# Implement encryption functionality in Objective C same as windows 7

Tags: c#, iphone, encryption, windows-7, aes

I want to implement encryption functionality in my iPhone application same as done in http://robtiffany.com/tag/hmacsha1.

I have reviewed lots of forum tried AES in iPhone but not getting exact result.

Can anybody help me for the same?

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

AES isn't available by default. You can use HASH encryption if you want, see [this](http://amcmillan.livejournal.com/155200.html) for an example...

Comment: Thanks for your tip. But i don't have to use MD5 i need to encrypt the data with a specified key and need to send to the server. Same thing is already implemented in windows 7. So i need to follow that way. Do you have any solution to implement that code in objective c?

Comment: It depends on how you impemented on the windows side... Be awere that these strings can be read out of the ipa file with some tools, so try to avoid storing passwords in a string on the iPhone